# What is this metric called?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, terminology, definition, riemann-sphere

Ahlfors -complex analysis p.20

Consider a stereographic projection between the 2-sphere and $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$ (i.e. one-point compactification of $\mathbb{C}$)

Let $z,w$ be complex numbers.

Let $d(z,w)$ denote the 2-norm distance between stereographic projections of $z,w$.

That is, $d(z,w)\triangleq \frac{2|z-w|}{\sqrt{(1+|z|^2)(1+|w|^2)}}$.

Moreover, define $d(\infty,z)=d(z,\infty)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}}$, for all complex $z$.

What is this metric $d$ called?

And does this metric induce topology on $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$ identical to that by one-point compactification?

Comment: So far, I have proved the question in the last sentence. So the only question left is: **What on earth this metric $d$ called?**

Comment: I know it as the spherical distance. I think it also has a name of a person, but I can't remember who it might have been.

Comment: @David Fischer: One can call it Fubini-Study metric, this this is the name for the standard metrics on the complex projective spaces of all dimensions.

Comment: @studiosus, somehow you typed in David Fischer, so Daniel will (as far as I know) not be notified of your comment by the system; only the first three letters really matter, (unless there are two people in a comment thread with the same first three letters, I suppose).

Comment: @DanielFischer, you got a suggestion for a name from studiosus, plus i put a comparison with the distance induced by great-circle travel on the sphere in my answer; Ahlfohrs, in this page, is allowing travel by digging through the Earth.

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for pinging. Yes, it's not the great-circle distance, but the Euclidean distance of the embedded sphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No apparent name, and it is not the same...the key line is on page 20, maybe I can figure out how to do a quote box. Nope, it keeps splitting lines within formulas, then putting in > characters.

"If the points on the sphere are denoted by  $(x_1,x_2,x_3),(x_1',
 x_2', x_3'),$ we have first  $$(x_1 - x_1')^2 +(x_2 - x_2')^2 + (x_3 -
 x_3')^2 =2-2(x_1 x_1' +x_2 x_2' +x_3 x_3') " $$

so he is taking the ambient distance in $\mathbb R^3$ rather than the submanifold distance on the surface of the sphere. You can see the difference through the lack of any mention of $\pi.$ If you do this recipe with the more complicated distance along the surface of the sphere by great circles, the longest distance possible would be $\pi$ rather than $2.$ Just look at the distance between $0$ and $\infty$ given by the final formula before the exercises.

Same topology, though.

EEDDIITTT, 12:42 pm

Given a complex number $z = x + i y,$ its stereographic projection back to the unit sphere is 
$$ \left( \frac{2x}{1 + x^2 + y^2},  \frac{2y}{1 + x^2 + y^2}, \frac{x^2 + y^2 - 1}{1 + x^2 + y^2} \right).   $$
You can check that the sum of the squares of these three expresssions is $1,$ and this lies along a straight line between $(x,y,0)$ and 
$(0,0,1).$

Next, given two unit vectors, we know the angle between them using the dot product. This is the same as the great-circle distance along the surface of the sphere. So, given vectors/ponts $a,b$ on the standard unit sphere, the great circle distance between them is 
$$ \arccos a \cdot b  $$

So, given $z = x + i y$ and $z_1 = x_1 + i y_1$ in the complex plane, the distance induced from great circles is 
$$ d_\bigcirc(z,z_1) = \arccos \left( \frac{4 x x_1 + 4 y  y_1 + (x^2 + y^2 - 1)(x_1^2 + y_1^2 - 1)}{(1 + x^2 + y^2)(1 + x_1^2 + y_1^2)} \right)  $$
and
$$ d_\bigcirc(z,\infty) = \arccos \left( \frac{ (x^2 + y^2 - 1)}{(1 + x^2 + y^2)} \right) = \arccos \left( \; 1 \; - \; \frac{ 2}{1 + x^2 + y^2} \; \right) $$

Comment: So, would it be OK to conclude: "Forget this metric"?

Comment: And what do you mean "it is not the same"? What do you mean, **it**?