# Prove $\frac{|a-c|}{\sqrt{(1+a^2)(1+c^2)}}\leq\frac{|a-b|}{\sqrt{(1+a^2)(1+b^2)}}+\frac{|b-c|}{\sqrt{(1+b^2)(1+c^2)}}$

Tags: inequality, problem-solving

Does anyone have a clever and direct proof of

$\frac{|a-c|}{\sqrt{(1+a^2)(1+c^2)}}\leq\frac{|a-b|}{\sqrt{(1+a^2)(1+b^2)}}+\frac{|b-c|}{\sqrt{(1+b^2)(1+c^2)}}$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3807438/.

Comment: @player3236 Oh-my-god this is so damn ingenious!!! THANK YOU A WHOLE LOT!!!