# What kinds of transformations preserve "metricness"?

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces

Trying to understand a step in a proof that's showing that the [metric in Ahlfors' *Complex Analysis*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741154/what-is-this-metric-called) is actually a metric:

Let $f: U \to V$ where $U, V \subseteq \mathbb{C}$, and suppose that $d(\cdot, \cdot)$ is a metric on $V$. When is $d(f(\cdot), f(\cdot))$ is a metric on $U$?

I would guess that $f$ at least needs to be one-to-one, since otherwise we would have $d(f(x_1), f(x_2))$ for $x_1 \neq x_2$. Is that a strong enough assumption, or is there more required?

Comment: Yes it is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, let $X$, $Y$ be sets, with $d:Y\times Y\to\mathbb{R}$ a metric on $Y$. Consider a function $f:X\to Y$ and $d':X\times X\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $d'(x,y):=d(f(x),f(y))$.

> **Lemma.** $d'$ is a metric on $X$ if and only if $f$ is injective.

*Proof.* "$\Rightarrow$" Assume that $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $x,y\in X$. Then $d(f(x),f(y))=0$ which is if and only if $d'(x,y)=0$ which implies that $x=y$ because $d'$ is a metric. $\Box$

"$\Leftarrow$" We check metric axioms:

1. Assume $d'(x,y)=0$. Which is if and only if $d(f(x),f(y))=0$ which is if and only if $f(x)=f(y)$ which is if and only if $x=y$ since $f$ is injective.
2. $d'(x,y)=d'(y,x)$ because $d(f(x),f(y))=d(f(y),f(x))$.
3. Let $x,y,z\in X$. Then $$d'(x,z)=d(f(x),f(z))\leq d(f(x),f(y))+d(f(y),f(z))=d'(x,y)+d'(y,z)$$

$\Box$